# DHL API > how to pass the parameter printFormat

Tags: api, dhl

I use the current REST API 2.1.1 of DHL Paket DE Versenden (Post & Paket Deutschland).

There i can pass a parameter namend **printFormat** to specify the label size. But I do not know where exactly to pass the printFormat.

When I pass it by the header like stated in the [documentation](https://developer.dhl.com/api-reference/parcel-de-shipping-post-parcel-germany-v2#operations-Shipments_and_Labels-createOrders) I get an error. And when I pass it within the post parameters as JSON I get also an error 400 > Blocking error.

Where the hell do I have to pass this parameter? Normally I can set the standard label in the profile of the user portal. But it seems that it's ignored.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter has to be passed as query parameter in the API URL:

```
POST /parcel/de/shipping/v2/orders?printFormat=910-300-600 HTTP/1.1Host: api-sandbox.dhl.com
```